# Transform pipe in Angular 6 with Observable or Promise

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, angular6, observable

I trying to set Pipe in angular 6 that convert text to other with using service (the method that returns observable)

I tried the following code, but I need to return a string instead of Promise

**Pipe:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TimeZoneService, TimeZone } from '../services/Global/timezone.service';
//import { resolve } from 'dns';
import { reject } from 'q';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Pipe({
  name: 'utcToText'
})
export class UtcToTextPipe implements PipeTransform {

  private timezoneLst: TimeZone[] = [];

  constructor(private _timezoneSvc : TimeZoneService) {}

  async transform(timezone: any, args?: any){
    this.timezoneLst = await this._timezoneSvc.getTimeZonesLst().toPromise();
     return this.timezoneLst.find(x => x.utc.indexOf(timezone) > -1).text;

}
}
```

**html:**

```
<span>{{subscription.time_zone |  utcToText}</span>
```

There is any way to make the asynchronous method of Promise /  Ovservabe to a synchronous function that returns synchronous such as String?

Thanks a lot for helpers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: No, I want to return string instead of Promise<string>

Comment: You don't need to return a string, you can return `Promise<string>` or `Observable<string>` and chain the `async` pipe to resolve the value. See the provided answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try instead returning an `Observable<string>` and chaining the `async` onto your existing pipe. Also you simply will not be able to return `string` with the async nature of your API calls.

Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TimeZoneService, TimeZone } from '../services/Global/timezone.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Pipe({ name: 'utcToText'})
export class UtcToTextPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private _timezoneSvc : TimeZoneService) {}

  transform(timezone: string, args?: any): Observable<string> {
    // this assumes getTimeZonesLst() returns an Observable<TimeZone[]>
    return this._timezoneSvc.getTimeZonesLst().pipe(
      map((timeZones: TimeZone[]) => {
        return timeZones.find(x => x.utc.indexOf(timezone) > -1).text;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<span>{{subscription.time_zone | utcToText | async}</span>
```

Here is a [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugtwts) async pipe in action derived from the [exponential pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes) example in the Angular documentation.

If you **really** need to use promises instead of observables for some reason:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TimeZoneService, TimeZone } from '../services/Global/timezone.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Pipe({ name: 'utcToText'})
export class UtcToTextPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private _timezoneSvc : TimeZoneService) {}

  transform(timezone: string, args?: any): Promise<string> {
    // this assumes getTimeZonesLst() returns an Observable<TimeZone[]>
    return this._timezoneSvc.getTimeZonesLst()
      .toPromise()
      .then((timeZones: TimeZone[]) => {
        return timeZones.find(x => x.utc.indexOf(timezone) > -1).text;
      })
  }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: You are the BEST! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: i was returning an observable with no luck. after converting it to a promise this worked great. i am not sure why promise works over an observable when using an async pipe.

Comment: @PhilNinan You would need to share what your code looks like. You can return an observable, but there may be an issue with how you are returning. For example if you have `subscribe()` anywhere in the observable you are returning, then you aren't returning the actual observable. Hard to say without seeing your exact code.

Comment: ah that was my problem i was calling subscribe.

      return this.service.getEvent(value).toPromise().then(res => {
        return res.description;
      });


vs


      return this.service.getEvent(value).subscribe(res => {
        return res.description;
      });

Comment: why does calling subscribe cause problems?

Comment: @PhilNinan Return type of `subscribe()` is not  `Observable<T>`. It's not an observable, but a [subscription](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription). As overall rule, never try to return anything from within a `subscribe()` either, it won't actually return anything.